# Label wont stay inside a table in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

so i have a label and a textbox in my web page and they wont stay inside the table. here is the code:

```
  <table position: absolute; bottom:0px; border="2" style="width: 100%">
     <asp:Label   ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Total de Marcações com os critérios indicados:"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalLinhas" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
       </table>
```

the table just stays under the label and text box does anyone knows why?
here is a print (that line under the label and textbox is the table)[image: pic] 
worth noticing this is all inside a div here is the div code

```
<div style=" float:left; width:50%; border-right:1px solid gray; border-left:1px solid gray; ">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to below

```
<table position: absolute; bottom:0px; border="2" style="width: 100%">
<tr>
<td>
     <asp:Label   ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Total de Marcações com os critérios indicados:"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalLinhas" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
       </table>
```

Try this